# Networking with two ASK-NCQ1338FA (Verizon 5G Gateway) and a TP-Link ER605 (as load balancer)

Tags: networking, wireless-router, setup, load-balancer, bridge-router

The Setup:
I have two [ASK-NCQ1338FA](https://www.verizon.com/support/verizon-internet-gateway-ask-ncq1338/) (Verizon Gateway Routers), a [TP-Link ER605](https://www.tp-link.com/us/business-networking/omada-sdn-router/er605/) (Only want use as a Load Balancer), and then a [Netgear RAXE450](https://www.netgear.com/home/wifi/routers/raxe450/) router. All the parts work fine, but a little weird.

When I pull out one of the ASK-NCQ1338FA ethernets from the WAN port of the ER605, the failover takes almost a minute to kick in, during that time its just no service. Any way to speed up the failover to the WAN that's still connected?